# Obtain 3D coordinates from various XZ coordinate pairs

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems, rotations, least-squares, projection-matrices

This is going to be my first question on this forum, I'll try to be as clear as possible!

The problem starts narrating that I am interested on obtaining the 3D coordinates of 50 points on a cylinder. For this, I have taken a picture of the cylinder as if standing on the Y axis of the following diagram:

[image: View of the XYZ axis, photo is taken as if standing on Y axis]

I take one picture, then rotate the cylinder $\theta_1$ degrees and take another, then rotate again $\theta_2$ degrees and repeat. I manage to take 50 pictures.

My problem starts when I try to solve it using linear algebra. So far I have two matrices $\mathbf{X}_{50\times50}$ and $\mathbf{Z}_{50\times50}$ and I also have a $\mathbf{\Theta}_{50\times1}$ matrix where I have stored the angles (which are given to me). They ask me to *obtain the original XYZ coordinates from all the given information*.

As I understand it, the **projection** of an original XYZ coordinate $(x_i, y_i, z_i)$ onto the XZ plane can be given by the following:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
  x^{'}_{1} \\
  z^{'}_{1} \\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
  x_{1} \\
  y_{1} \\
  z_{1} \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) & 0 \\
  \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

I understand the I have to **rotate** and then **project** (otherwise i'd be losing information). I know this system can be solved using least squares ($Ax=b$) where $A$ would be a combination of the Rotation and Projection matrix, something like :

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
  \mathbf{PR_{\theta_1}} & \mathbf{0}_{2x3} & \cdots & \cdots &\mathbf{0}_{2x3} \\
  \mathbf{0}_{2x3} & \mathbf{PR_{\theta_2}} & \mathbf{0}_{2x3} & \cdots & \vdots\\
  \vdots & \mathbf{0}_{2x3} & \ddots & & \vdots \\
  \vdots & \vdots & & & \vdots \\
  \mathbf{0}_{2x3} & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \mathbf{PR_{\theta_{50}}}\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

But once I solve that system, I obtain a solution matrix that has 50 different XYZ points for one angle, then another 50 different XYZ points for another angle, and that's where I don't really know what to do.

I'd really appreciate any advice, even if it implies starting over! Thanks in advance everyone.

EDIT: I apologize if I've broken any specific format rules or otherwise, I'm new to this forum and come from a very poor maths background.

EDIT2: I'll try to explain the process a bit better:

I take a picture of the XZ plane as if I was standing on the Y axis, so each one of the 3D points in the XYZ space gets projected onto the XZ plane with coordinates $x^{'}_{1}$ and $z^{'}_{1}$. Afterwards, there is a rotation of the cylinder around the Z-axis, with angle $\theta_1$. I take another picture, and obtain a different set of (x', z') coordinates. I do this for the 50 theta angles.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Exchange! Could you edit to clarify what your rotation axis is? Is it the $y$-axis?

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure how to edit it, the rotation is around the Z axis. So I take picture one, rotate theta around Z then take another picture and so on

Comment: You can edit your post by clicking the edit button just below the body of your post. Concerning the rotation question I had, I don't really understand what you mean when you say you are standing on the $y$-axis.

Comment: Hi! I managed to edit it, I hope it's a bit more clear now. Regarding the y-axis question: The picture is taken as if the camera were on the y axis, so an XYZ point gets projected on the XZ plane

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. It didn't click for me at first.